# Why are Arrays mimicking one another and resetting themselves?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How come I fail to remove the first items from these arrays and why do the new arrays mimic the old ones?

**(old arrays are sockets and ports, new arrays are w and w_ports)**

```
function pull(arr,val){
    for(var i = 0, j = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++){
        if(arr[i]!==val){
           arr[j++]=arr[i];
        }
    }
    arr.length=j;
}

var sockets = [1,2,3,4]
  , ports[8002,8003,8004,8005];

console.log(sockets,ports); // [ [1,2,3,4] , [8002,8003,8004,8005] ]
var m=sockets[0];
var m_port=ports[0];
var w=sockets;
pull(w,w[0]);

var w_ports=ports;
pull(w_ports,w_ports[0]);
console.log(w,w_ports);     // [ [2,3,4] , [8003,8004,8005] ]

sockets.unshift(m);
ports.unshift(m_port);
console.log(sockets,ports); // [ [1,2,3,4] , [8002,8003,8004,8005] ]
console.log(w,w_ports);     // [ [1,2,3,4] , [8002,8003,8004,8005] ]
```

I want to be left with sockets and ports unchanged but, w and w_ports to be missing the first items

***UPDATE:*** thanks [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo), [Akshat Singhal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2890157/akshat-singhal)

```
console.log(sockets,ports);
var m=sockets[0];
var m_port=ports[0];
var w=sockets.slice(1,sockets.length);
var w_ports=ports.slice(1,ports.length);
console.log(sockets,ports);
console.log(w,w_ports);
```

Can someone make it an answer so I can give a tick please...

Comment: This is because you are not creating array copies but just adding references. Declare a new array and then copy the values into it.

Comment: ok I will try.. I can't tick you if your right though (you should make that an answer)

Comment: `var w_ports = ports.slice();`

Comment: slice doesn't sound like what it does / can do to copy i mean

Comment: Just because the function name isn't obvious, doesn't mean it's not what you want. `ports.slice(0)` will give you a copy of the array - but be aware that any reference in that new array will be kept. If you have an array of arrays, for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not creating array copies but just adding references. Declare a new array and then copy the values into it.

Alternatively, you can use `var w_ports = ports.slice();` as suggested by [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo)